# Create a TensorFlow Input pipeline from GCS Bucket?

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, pipelines, google-cloud-platform

I wish to generate a TensorFlow input pipeline (i.e. **tf.data** pipeline) for an image classification project. The images stored in **a GCS bucket having access controls and is not publicly accessible**. And making it publicly accessible is not allowed by the Project Admin.

My service account has the required IAM Roles (but not Storage Admin) and I can access the bucket content using the Storage API (i.e. google.cloud.storage Python API). Also, I can authenticate my credentials using the google.oauth2.service_account Python API.

For your reference:

**CODE that I tried**:

```
img_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
    file_pattern="gs://"+GCS_BUCKET_NAME+"/dataset/train"
)
```

**ERROR that I got**:

```
PermissionDeniedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0118f212c92f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 img_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
      2     file_pattern="gs://"+GCS_BUCKET_NAME+"/dataset/train"
      3 )

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7260 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7261   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7262   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7263 
   7264 

PermissionDeniedError: {{function_node __wrapped__MatchingFiles_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 401 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
    '
     when reading gs://GCS_BUCKET_NAME/dataset [Op:MatchingFiles]
```

**Is there a way that I can use the service account credentials (as JSON file) to gain access and then create the tf.data input pipeline?**

Thanks in advance.